# Unable to load DLL ‘ABCpdf8-32.dll’:Access Denied

Tags: asp.net, dll, iis-7, configuration

I have configure website first time on server, all things works on local machine, it gives me an error **"Unable to load DLL ‘ABCpdf8-32.dll’:Access Denied"** on server.
I think this problem is due to permission, what type of permission I need to give and any other settings need to do for this.

Comment: Can you provide the full path to the DLL? To hazard a guess, the App Pool identity may not have enough permissions to access the Temporary ASP.NET Files directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to physical server with remote desktop or other tools : go to the Security tab in folder of this dll file and add `IIS_IUSRS` user to this folder. if you have a shared host : you can use control panel of your host and add read permission to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your host control panel and change permission for the folder that your DLL is located in.